# ggplot2 Create a new theme element outside of .elements_tree

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I need to create a new theme element for ggplot2

How can I add a **NEW** item to the `.elements_tree` data structure (for reference, it starts at line 263 [HERE](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/theme-elements.r))

For instance, I have a particular situation where I need to add another axis, so, I want to add theme objects: `axis.text.z`, `axis.title.z` etc...

I can add it manually to an individual plot object (say 'plot') by hacking into `plot$theme`, however, when I try to modify via `theme(...)` command, it gets non-validated via the `validate_element` function which starts at line 363, also on the same source file ([HERE](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/theme-elements.r) again).

If i create a local duplicate of `.elements_tree`, via something like:

```
.elements_tree = ggplot2:::.elements_tree
.elements_tree = c(.elements_tree,
                    axis.text.z  = el_def("element_text", "axis.text"),
                    axis.title.z = el_def("element_text", "axis.text"))
```

Then the new copy doesn't get picked up by the ggplot2 library instance, and hence nothing is achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTH:

```
et <- ggplot2:::.element_tree
et <- c(.element_tree,
        axis.text.z  = ggplot2:::el_def("element_text", "axis.text"),
        axis.title.z = ggplot2:::el_def("element_text", "axis.text"))

unlockBinding(".element_tree", asNamespace("ggplot2"))
assign(".element_tree", et, asNamespace("ggplot2"))
lockBinding(".element_tree", asNamespace("ggplot2"))
```

Comment: Doesn't get picked up by ggplot2. try:  'theme(axis.title.z=element_blank())'

Comment: Your solution works (ie the unlock, lock binding), the entries were missing names, ie, they should be added like `et$axis.text.z = ggplot2:::el_def("element_text", "axis.text")`